# Redirect all traffic (http and https) to root of another domain

Tags: .htaccess

I have a domain that's not to be used anymore. I want to redirect all from http://www.old.com/ and https://www.old.com to http://www.new.com/ (all links to root domain), no matter what page the user's attempted to access on www.old.com.

I have this code in .htaccess but it does not redirect the links with https (404):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule ^ https://www.new.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this simple rule to redirect your old domain to root of the new one :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this new rule.

Comment: does that pass on link juice?